# Making a multi-column dropdown menu from a button

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a multi-column (specifically 2 columns) dropdown menu from a button. 
I have tried using the [Upgrade Bootstrap 2 HTML to Bootstrap 3](http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader/) tool, and it doesn't fix anything but some .btn to .btn.btn-default stuff, which is fine.
The code was originally written in bootstrap 2.3.2, here is what it looks like normally:
[image: Bootstrap 2 Dropdown menu]

And under bootstrap 3 it looks like this:
[image: Bootstrap 3 Dropdown menu]

Here is the code i have:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">   Download
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical">
<a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Windows 32-bit</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Windows 64-bit</a>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical">
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Linux 32-bit</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Linux 64-bit</a>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have also checked out other posts on here before posting but none of them worked as I wanted it to work, or not work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This will make it float properly

```
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 260px;
  }

.btn-group-vertical {
    float: left;
    width: 46%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/Y0W9fwiCa4)